# Images not showing in production mode

Tags: ruby-on-rails

When I switch to production mode in Rails, CSS is loading but not images.  I have css in my /app/assets/stylesheets and and images in my /app/assets/images

My .css links to images with this:

```
background:url("/assets/str.png") repeat #fbfbfb;
```

I have restarted Rails, Nginx, and Passenger

```
touch home/user/railsapp/tmp/restart.txt   
passenger-config restart-app
sudo service nginx restart
```

I have tried:

```
rake assets:clobber
rake assets:precompile
```

My secret key is tied to the secrets.yml

I have this in my Nginx config:

```
  passenger_enabled on;
  passenger_app_env production;
```

Any suggestions on what else I can try?
Here is my environments/production.rb

```
rails.application.configure do
  # Settings specified here will take precedence over those in config/application.rb.

  # Code is not reloaded between requests.
  config.cache_classes = true

  # Eager load code on boot. This eager loads most of Rails and
  # your application in memory, allowing both threaded web servers
  # and those relying on copy on write to perform better.
  # Rake tasks automatically ignore this option for performance.
  config.eager_load = true

  # Full error reports are disabled and caching is turned on.
  config.consider_all_requests_local       = false
  config.action_controller.perform_caching = true

  # Disable serving static files from the `/public` folder by default since
  # Apache or NGINX already handles this.
  config.public_file_server.enabled = ENV['RAILS_SERVE_STATIC_FILES'].present?

  # Compress JavaScripts and CSS.
  config.assets.js_compressor = :uglifier
  # config.assets.css_compressor = :sass

  # Added this to allow images to be compiled from assets folder.
  config.assets.precompile += %w[*.png *.jpg *.jpeg *.gif]

  # Do not fallback to assets pipeline if a precompiled asset is missed.
  config.assets.compile = false

  # `config.assets.precompile` and `config.assets.version` have moved to config/initializers/assets.rb

  # Enable serving of images, stylesheets, and JavaScripts from an asset server.
  # config.action_controller.asset_host = 'http://assets.example.com'

  # Specifies the header that your server uses for sending files.
  # config.action_dispatch.x_sendfile_header = 'X-Sendfile' # for Apache
  # config.action_dispatch.x_sendfile_header = 'X-Accel-Redirect' # for NGINX

  # Mount Action Cable outside main process or domain
  # config.action_cable.mount_path = nil
 # config.action_cable.url = 'wss://example.com/cable'
  # config.action_cable.allowed_request_origins = [ 'http://example.com', /http:\/\/example.*/ ]

  # Force all access to the app over SSL, use Strict-Transport-Security, and use secure cookies.
  # config.force_ssl = true

  # Use the lowest log level to ensure availability of diagnostic information
  # when problems arise.
  config.log_level = :debug

  # Prepend all log lines with the following tags.
  config.log_tags = [ :request_id ]

  # Use a different cache store in production.
  # config.cache_store = :mem_cache_store

  # Use a real queuing backend for Active Job (and separate queues per environment)
  # config.active_job.queue_adapter     = :resque
  # config.active_job.queue_name_prefix = "zenapp_#{Rails.env}"
  config.action_mailer.perform_caching = false
  # Ignore bad email addresses and do not raise email delivery errors.
  # Set this to true and configure the email server for immediate delivery to raise delivery errors.
  # config.action_mailer.raise_delivery_errors = false

  # Enable locale fallbacks for I18n (makes lookups for any locale fall back to
  # the I18n.default_locale when a translation cannot be found).
  config.i18n.fallbacks = true

  # Send deprecation notices to registered listeners.
  config.active_support.deprecation = :notify

  # Use default logging formatter so that PID and timestamp are not suppressed.
  config.log_formatter = ::Logger::Formatter.new

  # Use a different logger for distributed setups.
  # require 'syslog/logger'
  # config.logger = ActiveSupport::TaggedLogging.new(Syslog::Logger.new 'app-name')

  if ENV["RAILS_LOG_TO_STDOUT"].present?
    logger           = ActiveSupport::Logger.new(STDOUT)
    logger.formatter = config.log_formatter
    config.logger = ActiveSupport::TaggedLogging.new(logger)
  end

  # Do not dump schema after migrations.
  config.active_record.dump_schema_after_migration = false
end
```

I just added the:

```
# Added this to allow images to be compiled from assets folder.
config.assets.precompile += %w[*.png *.jpg *.jpeg *.gif]
```

to the production.rb

**UPDATE**

I even renamed my .css to application.css.erb and changed the css to

```
background-image: url(<%= asset_path 'str.png' %>) repeat #fbfbfb;
```

It's still not working.

Answer (score 0):

You could try

```
background: url(image_path("str.png")) repeat #fbfbfb;
```

Comment: I tried that earlier today and had no luck.  The only way I have gotten it to work is by setting 'config.assets.compile' to true in production.rb  But I have read on here that this option should not be used.

Comment: Have you used image_path("str.png") or image_path("assets/str.png")? Try both just in case. In my applications, I don't need to add the assets folder. I have config.assets.compile set to false and it's working.

Comment: I just tried both now and it's not working.  I also ditched Passenger and switched to Puma which made no difference.  I have tried hosting assets through Nginx also.  It does the same thing.  I'm stumped.

Comment: I started looking at Nginx logs and noticed it was saying that it couldn't find the proper images in the public/assets folder.  I assumed that assets:recompile would move the files there.  I was storing images in /app/assets/images.  I moved images directly to the public directory and it is working now.